# How to use pandas to further process data in application/csv format

Tags: python, pandas

I get a data from api ,the content type is :application/csv . Now I want to load this data into pandas , how can I do this?
I try to use pandas.read_csv,but it failed.

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
dataframe = pd.read_csv(response,sep=';',header=0)
```

Comment: Access `response.content`, not the response object itself. If pandas needs a file-like object, you van wrap response.content in a BytesIO or StringIO object.

Comment: Pandas IO functions can take URLs directly. But you really should provide an error message. "It failed" is horribly vague.

Comment: Have you tried `dataframe = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), sep=';', header=0)`? (And first `from io import StringIO`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `response` is just a response object, not the actual `content` (`resonse.content` in bytes) or `text` (`response.text` in unicode). If you use `response.text` you get the text from the response. To use this wit `pd.read_csv()`, you can use `io.StringIO`, or first write the `response.text` to a file and then read the file with `pd.read_csv()`.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

url = 'your url'
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
dataframe = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), sep=';', header=0)
```